# Making things available only inside Ruby blocks

Tags: ruby, dsl

Is there any way to make methods and functions only available inside blocks? What I'm trying to do:

```
some_block do
    available_only_in_block
    is_this_here?
    okay_cool
end
```

But the `is_this_here?`, `okay_cool`, etc. only being accessible inside that block, not outside it. Got any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Are `okay_cool` and company variables or methods? If they're variables, declare them in the block and they will be local to the block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass an object with the methods that you want to be available into the block as an argument. This is a pattern that's widely used in Ruby, such as in [`IO.open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002239) or [XML builder](http://builder.rubyforge.org/).

```
some_block do |thing|
    thing.available_only_in_block
    thing.is_this_here?
    thing.okay_cool
end
```

Note that you can get closer to what you asked for using [`instance_eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Object.html#M000607) or [`instance_exec`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Object.html#M000608), but that's generally a bad idea as it can have fairly surprising consequences.

```
class Foo
  def bar
    "Hello"
  end
end

def with_foo &block
  Foo.new.instance_exec &block
end

with_foo { bar }      #=> "Hello"
bar = 10
with_foo { bar }      #=> 10
with_foo { self.bar } #=> "Hello
```

While if you pass an argument in, you always know what you'll be referring to:

```
def with_foo
  yield Foo.new
end

with_foo { |x| x.bar }      #=> "Hello"
bar = 10
x = 20
with_foo { |x| x.bar }      #=> "Hello"
```